# Footnote number not showing

Tags: footnotes, classicthesis

I'm using `classicthesis.sty` and my footnote numbers are not showing.

I do use this command at the beginning of each chapter:

```
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{
}
```

Do you think this is related? How do I show footnote numbers with `\footnote{}`? Thanks!

According to another post I read here, this should work, but it does not.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    dottedtoc,
    floatperchapter,
    parts
]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Test}
\vspace{30ex}

\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{something unnumbered} 

\newpage

There should be a footnote number here\footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Where does `\let\thefootnote\relax` come from and why are you using it? It just switches off footnote numbering globally.

Comment: I want to have the first footnote without numbering. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: You could do something like `\begingroup
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{something unnumbered} 
\endgroup` or better define a command that does that. Gimme a few minutes, i'll eat something and write up a bit more verbose answer.

Comment: @dorien Out of curiosity why do you need an unumbered footnote?

Comment: Another important thing, the author of `classicthesis` provided some commands and definitions, but either never uses them, commented important stuff out, or set *important* stuff at the wrong place. Having said that: either use `headinclude, footinclude` globally or set `\KOMAoptions{footinclude,headinclude}` before loading `classicthesis`. You can also do it afterwards, but then you have to `\recalctypearea` as well.

Comment: @dorien: Do you rather want a unnumbered footnote, but attached with some other footnote symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I put \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{something unnumbered}  between {} it works.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    dottedtoc,
    floatperchapter,
    parts
]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Test}
\vspace{30ex}

{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{something unnumbered}}

\newpage

There should be a footnote number here\footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really dependent on `classicthesis` and works with
other classes as well.
I defined a semantic command
`\describeContent` (you can rename it to your needs) so using it
again and again and again is easier. And much much more important, if you
decide to ga another way round you can change it globally.

The only thing you have to take care of is
the hyperref stuff.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
    dottedtoc,
    floatperchapter,
    parts
]{classicthesis}


\newcommand{\describeContent}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\let\thefootnote\relax%
\footnotetext{#1}%
\endgroup%
}

%\renewcommand{\describeContent}[1]{%
%   \marginpar{#1}%
%}
\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}
\describeContent{this is some introductory material}

There should be a footnote number here\footnote{test}.
How are the following footnotes numbered?\footnote{ascending
numbers}
\chapter{Lovemaking of pidgeons}
\describeContent{pidgeons are by far not as great as ducks}
Footnotes are numbered on a perchapter base\footnote{option
floatperchapter set}
\end{document}
```

[image]